# How to pass a variable to ngFor with ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, angular7, ngx-translate

I'm trying to iterate over a key/value json object which comes from the translation file of the ngx-translate.

This works fine:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of 'gallery.01.images' | translate | keyvalue">
    <p>{{item .key}}:{{item .value}}</p>
</div>
```

But if I want to include a variable in iterable object, it throws error below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of 'gallery.{{id}}.images' | translate | keyvalue">
    <p>{{item .key}}:{{item .value}}</p>
</div>
```

Error

```
emplate parse errors: Can't bind to '*ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

i18n/en.json

```
{
    "gallery": {
        "01: {
            "images": ["001", "002", "003"]
        },
        "02: {
            "images": ["006", "009"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `{{ }}` is only for displaying data while you are accesing to a variable.
If you want to iterate over a general array, you can do something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myCustomArray | translate | keyvalue">
    <p>{{item .key}}:{{item .value}}</p>
</div>
```

If you have any questions. Feel free to ask :)

Comment: do you mean I should construct `myCustomArray` first and then iterate over it? I think what you are suggesting is to build array first, but how do I know which language this array should be in, before feeding it to the `| translate` pipe?

Comment: I do not understand why this works, but it does. I'm just setting in constructor string `myCustomArray = "gallery." +  id + ".images"`

Comment: Hi, the problem is that we don't know how is your array built. So we are helping you in the general way.

myCustomArray is an array that was declared before at your `nameOfComponent.ts`. So we are iterating over that array and saving each iteration at `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is `*ngFor="let item of items"`, where Angular expects to get an array of iterable values in `items`.

I believe what you wanna do is to iterate twice over `gallery.id` and `images`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of gallery">
    <div *ngFor="let it of 'gallery.id.images' | translate | keyvalue">    
        <p>{{item .key}}:{{item .value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is not quite what I'm after, I want to display images of a specific user, whose id is passed as a parameter through url

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   <div *ngFor="let service of ('AboutUs.data' | translate)">
                      <p>{{service.title}}</p>
                      <p>{{service.description}}</p>
   </div>
```

with array in .json as below:

```
 "AboutUs": {
    "title": "About Us",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "Mission",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amesexercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      },
      {
        "title": "Plan",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor do consequat.",

      }]
}
```